# Unity singleton multiple request access ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am using MVC5 and Unity. I am a little confused reading about thread safe singletons. Do multiple users share the same singleton object? My understanding is that a singleton object would be created for every request and two users would each have their own singleton. Is this correct?

[UPDATE]

Let say I have a `Singleton` class with a `property` Instance to get the instance. Will two users accessing the website at the same time be accessing the same singleton object when calling `Instance`? What is the scope of an object? Is the scope shared among multiple users or does every user have their own scope? Will Instance return the same object for both users?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exact lifetime manager you use. If by "singleton" you mean the container controlled lifetime manager, then the instance will be shared by all users and will not be created for a lifetime of a request.

On the other hand, per http context lifetime managers do exactly what you expect.

Neither has the "singleton" in its name, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: You still don't say how this is related to Unity. If it is not, a singleton is a singleton, **shared between all requests of all users**.